# how can i extend the String object by adding a function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a function to the global String object by doing the following:

```
function repetirCaracteres() {

  String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function(palabra){
  const letras = palabra.split('')
  const repetir = letras.map(letras => letras.repeat(2))
  let letrasRepetidas = repetir.join('');
  return letrasRepetidas;
  }
  
 }

repetirCaracteres()
```

I want to do a function that receives a string and each character of the string is repeated twice.

Logic seems ok to me but for some reason i have the following error:

```
String prototype is read only, properties should not be added.
```

Comment: What gives you that error?

Comment: @Unmitigated i edited my question with the complete block of code. I am trying this in codesandbox.

Comment: This isn't actually an error, but likely an ESLint warning. Your code will still work, but it's recommended to not modify built-in prototypes.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The ECMA Script specification allows the `String.prototype` object to get user defined properties.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: But taking a step back, ... *why* do you want to define a *method* on a prototype when that method doesn't use `this`? It seems you don't need a method then.

Comment: @tukitooo1998 please add an example how you intend to use/call this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know, why it did not work for you. It works here without problems:

```js
String.prototype.rr=function(){
 return this.split("").map(c=>c+c).join("")}
console.log("ABC".rr())
```

In my snippet I used `this` as the input string. Without `this` there would be no reason for defining a `String.prototype` method.